# What is a Small Italized T Located where a Power could be?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

In some equations I have found a small italized 'T' in a location where I would expect to see a 'power to' number.

The answer may be very simple but I do not have the vocabulary yet to perform an effective search for an answer to my question.

Examples of this are in the book 'Introduction to Statistical Learning'.  A copy can be obtained legally and freely at the link below. Examples can be seen on page 338 under section 9.1.1 'What is a hyperplane?'

http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/

Comment: It is probably the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of a matrix.

Comment: [You can format maths with MathJax.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) Much simpler in the long run than having people download whole book for one symbol.

Comment: @Ennar Thanks, I will look at MathJax and use that where possible in future. I was not aware of it.

Comment: @Gribouillis I believe that you are correct, so will happily accept this if you place it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of a matrix.